# Does glassfish resolve the path to libraries correctly?

Tags: jar, glassfish

I am interested in this question due to the [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062177/making-pom-xml-with-one-library-provided-and-one-included) I described here. How does Glassfish look for the required classes anyway? Suppose there are two libraries in pom.xml of the application (in dependencies), one is declared with scope **provided**, another is declared with standard scope.

Therefore, I have two libraries - A.jar is in Glassfish lib folder, B.jar is in WEB-INF/lib of the war module that I deploy.

What is the order of resolving the dependencies here? I assume that:

- First look in the WEB-INF/lib folder if any jar matches the class.
- After that look in Glassfish/lib folder if any jar matches the class.

Is that correct? Is the situation when class in A.jar refences a class in B.jar, legal for such a configuration, and vice versa?

To be more specific, I have Glassfish 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

According to class loader [documentation for GF2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/820-4336/beade/index.html) I would say vice versa.

> Note that the class loader hierarchy is not a Java inheritance hierarchy, but a delegation hierarchy. In the delegation design, a class loader delegates class loading to its parent before attempting to load a class itself. If the parent class loader cannot load a class, the class loader attempts to load the class itself. In effect, a class loader is responsible for loading only the classes not available to the parent. Classes loaded by a class loader higher in the hierarchy cannot refer to classes available lower in the hierarchy.

**note:** Related documentation for GF3.1 is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beadf.html#scrolltoc) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/gfqpi.html#scrolltoc)

However you may influence the behavior through glassfish specific descriptor with

```
<class-loader delegate="true/false"/>
```

You can find more about it following the first link